# Broken Phone Power Button and ADB not detecting device. NEED HELP!

Tags: recovery-mode, data-recovery

So the power button on my phone (Asus Zenfone 3 laser) no longer works and the phone is powered off. I have charged it up and gotten it to the android recovery menu by holding down power and simultaneously plugging it into my laptop. Unfortunately, I don't think USB debugging is turned on as adb devices and fastboot devices comes up empty. The phone does charge from being plugged in.

Since the power button doesn't work, I can move up and down in the recovery menu all I want using the volume keys, but cant select an option (which requires the power button).

Does anyone have a method of just getting it to turn on that doesn't require opening up the phone (as I don't want to buy the special screw driver to do so). I just want the photos inside, the phone is pretty much scrap metal.

Comment: If bootloader is unlocked you can boot twrp recovery from fastboot. fastboot mode is the other vol-key. you don't need usb-debugging for fastboot its just a cable/driver thing, and twrp has adb access by default

Comment: there is also a fastboot setting to boot when charging, try `fastboot oem off-mode-charge disable`

Comment: Thank you. I tried the second option and I think it may have worked. I used it in cmd and it said successfully finished. Will know if it worked or not tomorrow once my phone exits fast boot mode so I can put it on charge

Comment: Thank You SOOOOO much. It worked. I was a little scared it wouldn't since secure boot is enabled but it did. Ur my hero :)))))))